# I have an app/web application in mind but I can't find the answers on what I would need to build it

Tags: android, ios, json, mobile-application, user-profile

Basic overview of this app isn't new or ground breaking. most importantly it's centered around the google maps api using json. That part I have under control, i have studied the google maps api up and down.

The issue I am having is figuring out how to create users for the app. I need to not only allow(require) users to create a profile, but for them to be able to add and view points on the map. Again I am not concerned about the map, only the user profiles.

I have read that javascript isn't secure enough to use to create users (by the way i can't figure out the term I'm looking for ie. user profiles? user area? users? i don't know how to phrase it) but I know that I would like to store the data from the user as json so that I can easily call it. I could say that I am considering using java or ruby on rails but the truth is I don't know the first thing about what I am trying to do (hence not being able to find what I am looking for). I would also like to use a titanium like structure so as to make it friendly for all platforms.

payments will be involved so it needs to be secure, but the data also needs to be usable on the web. i'd like to allow the user to access there product and all of the same functionailty that comes with it on the website (like facebook).

I'm just looking for a lead or something that will help me to find the info I need. if you know what you are talking about and you want to write me a book on the matter please do so. I've been searching for days and can't find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use Google's OAuth2 method for performing authentication, which should also make it easy to integrate Google Wallet for payment stuff. As for saving data regarding the user, since you are relying on OAuth2 for your authentication you could just keep track of their Google account (e.g., gmail address) and the OAuth2 Refresh Token. The refresh token would allow you to re-authenticate the OAuth2 session without requiring additional user authentication.

Note: The OAuth2 Refresh Token will only be returned the first time the user grants your application access. Check out these pages:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

https://developers.google.com/wallet/

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Briggs that does shed some much needed light on payments. You have to love google for their supply of resources with development. Would you be able to offer any advice on where to look for info on creating the "user area" to begin with?

Comment: If you use OAuth2, basically you would not be creating users yourself. You would be using their Google accounts as their user accounts. This prevents you from needing to store any sensitive information. Instead all you need to do is store some manner of associating their user account to the database of points/etc they've created for the account. This could be something simple like their gmail email address. So you might have an SQL statement like "SELECT ALL FROM Points WHERE Account='john@gmail.com'". Google handles the authentication, you just store the points and refresh tokens. That help?

Comment: Yes actually I didn't realize that it worked like that. it does seam though that it takes some control away on my side. May that isn't a bad thing though. Thanks

Comment: There are certainly other options. I mean, if you wanted to fully control the user accounts then you could do a few things. You could use SSL enabled connections for the transmission of data. You could avoid storing passwords in the database by doing something like a one-way hash. Instead of comparing the password the user provides, you would hash the value they provide and then compare that to the stored password-hash. This way there is no way to retrieve the password even if the DB is compromised somehow. You would likely want to create some kind of session cookie for log-ins in this case.

Comment: I lack the skills to be able to do anything like that. You have reinforced your first suggestion. So to clarify, Oauth2 will allow my app to create and verify users which in turn will give my app the ability to take payment through google?

Comment: You can also look at providers such as Parse.com